# Convert string y/n/null to Boolean true/false/null in Java

Tags: java

I am getting data from database in string format which is either 'y', 'n' or null(empty).  I need to convert this value to Boolean 'y' to true,  'n' to false and null to null.

```
string 'y' -> true (Boolean)
string 'n' -> false (Boolean)
string null -> null (Boolean)
```

I tried bunch of methods but seems like null is always converting to false.

I have tried following methods

```
"Y".equalsIgnoreCase(str)
 BooleanUtils.toBooleanObject(str)
```

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks in Advance

Comment: *"I tried bunch of methods"* Which ones? Did you try writing code? E.g. `if` statement or using the `? :` ternary conditional operator? What have you tried? --- Also, what should happen if the string is some other value?

Comment: thanks for the response.  Database can save only y, n or null value. We don't save any other values in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make sure to use `Boolean` (capital B).

```
String foo = "y";
Boolean b = foo == null ? null : "y".equals(foo);
```

This will set `b` to `null` (if `foo` is `null`), or to `true` (if `foo == "y"`) or `false` in all other cases.

If you want it as a function:

```
private Boolean getBooleanFromDB( String value ) {
    Boolean result = value == null ? null : "y".equals(value);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I really appreciate your help

Comment: if it solves your problem, it would be nice, if you could accept my answer by clicking the checkmark next to it, because it would mark the Question as answered.

If it doesn't answer your question, please let me know how I can helpt.